# How to calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and Mean Signed Error (MSE) using pandas/numpy/python math libray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, statistics

I have a dataset like below. In this dataset, there are different colored thermometers, and given a 'True' or reference temperature, how different they measure according to some measurement methods 'Method 1' and 'Method 2'.

I am having trouble calculating two important parameters that I need which are **Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and Mean Signed Error (MSE)**. I want to use the non-NaN values for each method and print the result.

I was able to get the to a point where I can return a two column series of index and sum, but the problem in this case is that I need to divide by the number of method values summed, which changes depending on how many NaN's there are in a row. And I do NOT want to just skip an entire row just because there is an NaN in it.

| number | date | Thermometer | True Temperature | Method 1 | Method 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1/1/2021 | red | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | red | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | red | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.23 |
| 3 | 1/1/2021 | green | 0.2 | 0.4 | NaN |
| 4 | 1/1/2021 | green | 1 | 1 | 0.23 |
| 5 | 1/1/2021 | yellow | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.32 |
| 6 | 1/1/2021 | yellow | 0.1 | NaN | 0.4 |
| 7 | 1/1/2021 | yellow | 1.3 | 0.5 | 0.54 |
| 8 | 1/1/2021 | yellow | 1.5 | 0.5 | 0.43 |
| 9 | 1/1/2021 | yellow | 1.5 | 0.5 | 0.43 |
| 10 | 1/1/2021 | blue | 0.4 | 0.3 | NaN |
| 11 | 1/1/2021 | blue | 0.8 | 0.2 | 0.11 |

My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('default'

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', index_col=0)
data

data["M1_ABS_Error"]= abs(data["True_Temperature"]-data["Method_1"])
data["M2_ABS_Error"]= abs(data["True_Temperature"]-data["Method_2"])

MAE_Series=data[['Name', 'M1_ABS_Error', 'M2_ABS_Error' ]]
MAE_Series.sum(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

but output is something like this at the moment, which doesn't specify which color thermometer this belongs to, and I would like this to print out in a way that is easy to associate it with which it belongs. Also, as I mentioned, this does not yet account for how to divide by the number of values/methods in the given row to account for NaN. :

```
0       4.94
1       3.03
2      11.88
3       3.28
4       8.14
5       7.80
6       2.76
7       2.71
```

I would appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

I think I understand now, let me know if this is what you want

MAE:

```
df['MAE'] = df[['M1_ABS_Error','M2_ABS_Error']].mean(axis = 1)
df
```

produces

```
    date      Thermometer      True_Temperature    Method_1    Method_2    M1_ABS_Error    M2_ABS_Error    MAE
--  --------  -------------  ------------------  ----------  ----------  --------------  --------------  -----
 0  1/1/2021  red                           0.2         0.2        0.5              0              0.3   0.15
 1  1/1/2021  red                           0.6         0.6        0.3              0              0.3   0.15
 2  1/1/2021  red                           0.4         0.6        0.23             0.2            0.17  0.185
 3  1/1/2021  green                         0.2         0.4      nan                0.2          nan     0.2
 4  1/1/2021  green                         1           1          0.23             0              0.77  0.385
 5  1/1/2021  yellow                        0.4         0.4        0.32             0              0.08  0.04
 6  1/1/2021  yellow                        0.1       nan          0.4            nan              0.3   0.3
 7  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.3         0.5        0.54             0.8            0.76  0.78
 8  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.5         0.5        0.43             1              1.07  1.035
 9  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.5         0.5        0.43             1              1.07  1.035
10  1/1/2021  blue                          0.4         0.3      nan                0.1          nan     0.1
11  1/1/2021  blue                          0.8         0.2        0.11             0.6            0.69  0.645
```

and for MSE (*Signed* error)

```
df["MSE"]= df[['Method_1','Method_2']].mean(axis = 1)- df['True_Temperature']
```

produces

```
    date      Thermometer      True_Temperature    Method_1    Method_2    M1_ABS_Error    M2_ABS_Error    MAE     MSE
--  --------  -------------  ------------------  ----------  ----------  --------------  --------------  -----  ------
 0  1/1/2021  red                           0.2         0.2        0.5              0              0.3   0.15    0.15
 1  1/1/2021  red                           0.6         0.6        0.3              0              0.3   0.15   -0.15
 2  1/1/2021  red                           0.4         0.6        0.23             0.2            0.17  0.185   0.015
 3  1/1/2021  green                         0.2         0.4      nan                0.2          nan     0.2     0.2
 4  1/1/2021  green                         1           1          0.23             0              0.77  0.385  -0.385
 5  1/1/2021  yellow                        0.4         0.4        0.32             0              0.08  0.04   -0.04
 6  1/1/2021  yellow                        0.1       nan          0.4            nan              0.3   0.3     0.3
 7  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.3         0.5        0.54             0.8            0.76  0.78   -0.78
 8  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.5         0.5        0.43             1              1.07  1.035  -1.035
 9  1/1/2021  yellow                        1.5         0.5        0.43             1              1.07  1.035  -1.035
10  1/1/2021  blue                          0.4         0.3      nan                0.1          nan     0.1    -0.1
11  1/1/2021  blue                          0.8         0.2        0.11             0.6            0.69  0.645  -0.645
```

### Original answer

It is not entirely clear what you want, but somewhat guessing here, is this what you are after? If you `groupby` by color and apply `mean` to the `ABS  columns within  each group

```
data.groupby('Thermometer', sort = False)[['M1_ABS_Error','M2_ABS_Error']].mean()
```

you get this

```
        M1_ABS_Error    M2_ABS_Error
Thermometer     
red     0.066667    0.256667
green   0.100000    0.770000
yellow  0.700000    0.656000
blue    0.350000    0.690000
```

Here, for example, the first top left number '0.066667`is the average of the`M1_ABS_Error`column for those Thermometers that are`red`. Similar to others. NaNs are skipped within each color/column

to get MSE (which normally means Mean *Squared* Error so I assume this is what you are after) you can do

```
import numpy as np
data["M1_Sqr_Error"]= (data["True_Temperature"]-data["Method_1"])**2
data["M2_Sqr_Error"]= (data["True_Temperature"]-data["Method_2"])**2
data.groupby('Thermometer', sort = False)[['M1_Error','M2_Error']].apply(lambda v: np.sqrt(np.mean(v)))
```

to get

```
        M1_Error    M2_Error
Thermometer     
red     0.115470    0.263881
green   0.141421    0.770000
yellow  0.812404    0.769909
blue    0.430116    0.690000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I am looking for is The Mean Absolute Error(MAE) which is is the average of all absolute errors. Basically, you

1. Find all of your absolute errors, xi – x.
2. Add them all up.
3. Divide by the number of errors. For example, if you had 10 measurements, divide by 10.

Ideally, I would get a MAE value for each line by index. Not just for "all red" but for each individual one. The trouble i am having is to figure out how to divide each row's absolute error sum, because some have NaN in 'Method'. So in this case, some may need to divide by 2 and others by 1

Comment: As for MSE, I do mean Mean Signed Error or Mean Signed Difference. https://wiki2.org/en/Mean_signed_deviation

Comment: thank you very much! that is precisely what I was looking for. Very thorough and clear to follow explanation.@piterbarg

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use ready made and tested and correctly defined functions from libraries (here scikit-learn). **Note: I give here answer for MAE==mean absolute error and MSE==mean squared error (more usually one uses root mean squared error RMSE) and NOT for mean signed error, which is very seldom used**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

data = {"predicted": [11.3, 22.2, 51.4], "true": [10.1, 25.2, 60.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mae = mean_absolute_error(data["predicted"], data["true"])
mse = mean_squared_error(data["predicted"], data["true"], squared=True)

print(f"mae:{round(mae,2)} mse:{round(mse,2)}")
```